# How to Solve a System of Equations with a constructor on python

Tags: python, numpy

I am in Uni and I am required to do a specific task the task is:

> Create a class that represents a system of linear algebra equations
> (system of equations), finding roots and checking whether some set of
> numbers exists as a solution of the system. Based on this class,
> create descendant classes representing systems of two and three linear
> equations, respectively, with two and three unknowns. By randomly
> generating the data, to find the solution of systems of linear
> algebraic equations of both types.

The idea is that I Have to use a constructor and a solving method like this in order to solve the System of Equations. I still have to make a descendant class after but first I need to fix the main code.

```
import numpy as np
class Linear:
    # linear equation ax + by + c = 0
    def __init__(self, a, c, x):
        self.a = np.array([[8, 3, -2], [-4, 7, 5], [3, 4, -12]])  # coefficient of X's           8X + 3Y - 2z   = 9
        self.c = np.array([9, 15, 35])                            # free term of Equation       -4X + 7Y + 5Z   = 15
        self.x = np.linalg.solve(a, c)                                                        #  3X + 4Y - 12Z  = 35
    def solve(self):
        if self.x

r1 = Linear(8, 3, -2)
print(r1.solve())
```

I've found on the web that you can use numpy easily to skip all the big steps however I'm having trouble solving and placing the code together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should not contain any sample numbers.  You should just accept `a` and `c` as parameters, and store `self.a = a` and `self.c = c`.  You don't pass  in `x`, since that's an output of the class.  And you don't do the solving until you call `solve()`.

Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
class Linear:
    # linear equation ax + by + c = 0
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        self.a = a
        self.c = c

    def solve(self):
        return np.linalg.solve(self.a, self.c)


r1 = Linear(
   [[8, 3, -2], [-4, 7, 5], [3, 4, -12]],
   [9, 15, 35]
)
print(r1.solve())
```

Output:

```
[-0.58226371  3.22870478 -1.98599767]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main source was answered by others but I adjusted them in order to fit the main task that was given by my uni. so I will post the final result to my main task here.

```
import numpy as np


class linear:
    # linear equation  bx + c = 0
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        self.a = a
        self.c = c

    def solve(self):
        return np.linalg.solve(self.a, self.c)


class two_unknown_lin(linear):
    # linear equation with 2 unknown ax + by + c = 0
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        super().__init__(a, c)

    def solve(self):
        return np.linalg.solve(self.a, self.c)


class three_unknown(two_unknown_lin):
    # linear equation with 2 unknown ax + by + cz + d = 0
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        super().__init__(a, c)

    def solve(self):
        return np.linalg.solve(self.a, self.c)


r2 = two_unknown_lin(
    [[1, 3], [2, 8]],
    [6, -12]
)
print("2 variable unknown roots are :", r2.solve())

r1 = three_unknown(
    [[8, 3, -2], [-4, 7, 5], [3, 4, -12]],
    [9, 15, 35]
)
print("3 variable unknown roots are :", r1.solve())
```

Comment: Since the subclasses are all identical, you don't need any code at all.  Just `class two_unknown_lin(linear):` / `pass` would suffice.